# Rewrite a query with "LEVEL" in snowflake

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, recursive-query

How can I write this SQL query into SNOWFLAKE?

SELECT LEVEL lv FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;

Answer (score 1):

You can find some good starting points by using CONNECT BY (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/connect-by.html) and here (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-hierarchical.html).

Snowflake is also supporting recursive CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to duplicate the rows three times. For a fixed, small multiplier such as 3, you could just enumerate the numbers:

```
select c.lv, a.*
from abc a
cross join (select 1 lv union all select 2 union all select 3) c
```

A more generic approach, in the spirit of the original query, uses a standard recursive common-table-expression to generate the numbers:

```
with cte as (
    select 1 lv
    union all select lv + 1 from cte where lv <= 3
)
select c.lv, a.*
from abc a
cross join cte c
```

Comment: What table is numns?

Comment: @HappySnowman: my bad, that's a typo, it should be `cte`. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There is *level* in snowflake. The differences from Oracle are:

- In snowflake it's neccesary to use *prior* with *connect by* expression.
- And you can't just select level - there should be any existing column in the select statement.

Example:

```
SELECT LEVEL, dummy FROM 
    (select 'X' dummy ) DUAL 
CONNECT BY prior LEVEL <= 3;

LEVEL   DUMMY
1   X
2   X
3   X
4   X
```

Answer (score 0):

As per @Danil Suhomlinov post, we can further simplify using COLUMN1 for special table dual single column:

SELECT LEVEL, column1 FROM dual
CONNECT BY prior LEVEL <= 3;
LEVEL | COLUMN1
------+--------
1 |
2 |
3 |
4 |